# Why doesn't my MySQLdb work? (Python)

Tags: python, mysql

I want to execute a db query from python:

```
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='', db='macadd', port=3306)
c = mydb.cursor()
c.execute("""INSERT INTO macadd.scanned (mac, first_time_seen, last_time_seen) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", ("0A:1B:2C:3D:4E:5F", "2015-09-20 19:00:18", "2015-09-20 19:03:57"))

mydb.close()
print "Done"
```

That's my query to input a value to my database. When I executed, it said done and nothing wrong. But, when I look at the data, nothing comes up. My table is empty.

But when U use the `_mysql` module:

```
import _mysql

mydb = _mysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='', db='macadd', port=3306)
mydb.query("INSERT INTO macadd.scanned (mac, first_time_seen, last_time_seen) VALUES ('0A:1B:2C:3D:4E:5F', '2015-09-09 00:00:00', '2015-09-02 00:00:00')")
print "done"
```

It said done as well, nothing wrong, and when when I look at the data, there is one record that has been imported.

Actually I would like to use the MySQLdb module instead of the _mysql one to execute this code:

```
("""INSERT INTO macadd.scanned (mac, first_time_seen, last_time_seen) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", ("0A:1B:2C:3D:4E:5F", "2015-09-20 19:00:18", "2015-09-20 19:03:57"))
```

But, I don't know why it doesn't work. Is there anyone knows how to make this works so I can use MySQLdb module?

Comment: I notice that you omitted the `mydb.close()` statement in the second code. Could that be the answer?

Comment: iirc, you should commit before closing the connection. `mydb.commit()`

Comment: @adonis yep, that's it. I can reproduce this on my system. Please turn this into an answer.

Comment: It should also be noted, that you can turn autocommit on with `mydb.autocommit(1)` making `commit` unnecessary. I was actually a bit surprised to find transaction mode to be the default.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jos @adonis @nephente! I put `mydb.commit()` and It works

Comment: You're welcome, but someone should still write an answer. You can do it yourself and accept your own answer, if @adonis doesn't feel like it.

Comment: @Barata: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

Mysql DB supports transaction. According to PEP-249:

"if the database supports an auto-commit feature, this must be initially off" and "closing a connection without committing the changes first will cause an implicit rollback to be performed".

You can

call `mydb.commit()` to commit your changes to the db

or

*(nephente)* set autocommit using `mydb.autocommit(True)`

Comment: Oh, maybe I should've read the PEP. Then I wouldn't have been suprised about auto-commit being initally off :-)